# Buffer not working in GeoPandas

Tags: python, buffer, geopandas, shapely, geodataframe

This seems pretty simple but I can't seem to create a buffer around a `GeoDataFrame`. I'm making this buffer so that it will be the extent of the axes instead of the original layer. This is to make the plot more zoomed out.

```
site_bdry = gpd.read_file(boundary_json)
site_bdry = site_bdry.to_crs("EPSG:26913")
site_bdry["geometry"] = site_bdry.geometry.buffer(10)
ax = site_bdry.plot(figsize=(10,11), facecolor="none", edgecolor="red", linewidth=2)
ax.set_xlim(421964, 469670) # hard-coded, need to set ax's extent with buffered gdf
ax.set_ylim(3565424, 3603367) 
ax.set_title("New Mexico Unit 29, County Rd F004, Dell City, NM 79837, USA @ -105.5, 32.4")
cx.add_basemap(ax, crs=site_bdry.crs.to_string(), zoom=10)
```

The result is still the unbuffered/original layer.
[image]

I checked the geometry and CRS and it's as expected.

```
display(site_bdry)
site_bdry.crs
```

[image]

The buffer line is from here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/253387/146811

Comment: you're only buffering by 10 meters. That's only a fraction of a percent of the size of the original geometry. You're not going to see the difference at this scale.

Comment: You're right. I didn't think of it. Thanks. The buffer is now showing.